# Update page after async results

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

Hy, 
I currently developing a web page to show the result of differents requests on differents databases.

I manage to lunch all the requests asynchronously to gain time, but my page didn't load after the last result. It's a probleme because some requests during around 10 seconds.

So I would like to show the page direcly with a spinner next to each request and replace it when the result come by.

But I really don't know don't how to do it and what's the best way to do that... UpdatePanel, Ajax, jQuery or other...

My page is construct with a user control inside a repeater for each database I connect, and a repeater for each request on each databases.

For the moment this is what I have :

Main page :

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptDbSummary" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptDbSummary_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <uc1:DbSummary runat="server" ID="DbSummary1" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Main page Code behind :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindDbSummary();
    }

    protected void rptDbSummary_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ucDbSummary ctrl = (ucDbSummary)e.Item.FindControl("DbSummary1");
        var db = (DatabaseApplicatif)e.Item.DataItem;
        ctrl.BindData(db);
    }

    private void BindDbSummary()
    {
        var dbs = confManager.Platforms.SelectMany(p => p.Databases);
        rptDbSummary.DataSource = dbs;
        rptDbSummary.DataBind();
    }
```

User control :

```
        <table class="tableSummary">
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptDbQuery" OnItemDataBound="rptDbQuery_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQueryName"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQueryData"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw"></i></asp:Label> </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </table>
```

User Control code behind :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected async void rptDbQuery_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (IpQuery)e.Item.DataItem;
        var name = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblQueryName");
        var req = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblQueryData");

        try
        {
            name.Text = (string)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("RunReport", item.Label, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);

            var res = await Task.Run(() => doAsyncOperation(item.Postgre, item.IpAdr, item.Sql));
            req.Text = res;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            req.Text = string.Format("error : {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public async Task<string> doAsyncOperation(bool postgre, string ipAdr, string request)
    {
        var dbManager = new DbLogManager();
        var res = await dbManager.GetRequestResult(postgre, ipAdr, request);
        return res;
    }

    public void BindData(DatabaseApplicatif db)
    {
        var queries = new List<IpQuery>();

        lblDbName.Text = db.Label;
        foreach (var q in db.Queries)
        {
            queries.Add(new IpQuery
            {
                Postgre = db.Postgre,
                IpAdr = db.IPServer,
                Label = q.Label,
                Sql = q.SQL
            });
        }

        rptDbQuery.DataSource = queries;
        rptDbQuery.DataBind();
    }
```

Thanks by advance

Comment: Looks like you're going to need some JavaScript on the client that makes the request after the page loads and then updates the DOM appropriately.

Comment: Yes sure but I don't know how. I understand the process like in this post [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx). But I didn't see how to implement it for each request in the repeater. And I would prefer not to put the request on the client side